# Attempted to call function from the global namespace on Silex

Tags: php, silex

I have this error when I call my route.

```
Attempted to call function "VisiteurType" from the global namespace.
```

However I have the line

`use PPE_PHP\Form\Type\VisiteurType;`

But this is never used. The file exist :

[image: Path]

On the call, VisiteurType()is indefined :

```html
$app->match('/admin/visiteur/add', function(Request $request) use ($app) {
    $visiteur = new Visiteur();
    $visiteurForm = $app['form.factory']->create(VisiteurType(), $visiteur);
    $visiteurForm->handleRequest($request);
    if ($visiteurForm->isSubmitted() && $visiteurForm->isValid()) {
        $app['dao.visiteur']->save($visiteur);
        $app['session']->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Le visiteur a bien été créé.');
    }
    return $app['twig']->render('visiteur_form.html.twig', array(
        'nom' => 'Nouveau visiteur',
        'visiteurForm' => $visiteurForm->createView()));
})->bind('admin_visiteur_add');
```

I don't understand when is my error.

Comment: You're missing a `new` in your `create` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of form.factory has to be a string ([see doc](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.html#method_create)).